# Error in Java project: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to JSONObject

Tags: java, json

I am getting this error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to JSONObject".

I don't know what to change because my transactions is a JSONArray of JSONObjects. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks!

```
           for (JSONObject transaction : transactions) {
                if (transaction.getString("direction").equals("OUT")) {
                    int amount = transaction.getInt("amount");
                    int rounded = (amount + 99) / 100 * 100;
                    int roundUpAmount = rounded - amount;
                    roundUpAmounts.add(roundUpAmount);
                }
            } 
           return roundUpAmounts;
    }
```

Comment: You can either use `instanceOf` to cast the `Object` reference to a `JSONObject`, or loop over the indices of the array and call `transactions.getJSONObject()`, which will throw an exception if one of your elements is not a `JSONObject`.

Comment: Have a look at the declaration of `JSONArray`: `public class JSONArray implements Iterable<Object> `, so when you use a foreach loop, each element will be an `Object`. (of course the actual objects will be `JSONObject`, `JSONArray`, `String` ans so on, but you can't assume that they are anything more specific than `Object`)

Answer (score 1):

If you cast each element of the array explicitly, it should work.
Like this:

```
for (Object obj : transactions) {
    JSONObject transaction = (JSONObject) obj;
    if (transaction.getString("direction").equals("OUT")) {
        int amount = transaction.getInt("amount");
        int rounded = (amount + 99) / 100 * 100;
        int roundUpAmount = rounded - amount;
        roundUpAmounts.add(roundUpAmount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It hasn't worked yet. 

If I do this, I can no longer use "getString" and "getInt", I think because it doesn't see the transaction as a JSONObject. But if I try to access "direction" and "amount" in the normal object way e.g. transaction.amount, that doesn't work either.

Comment: I figured it out, amount is an object inside the main object not an int. That wasn’t the error message I was getting though!